# jasmine - creating nested spy object

Tags: jasmine, mocking

Is there a way to get Jasmine to generate spies so that such a test will pass:

```
it('a', function () {
  const a = jasmine.createSpyObj('a', ['b', 'c.d', 'e.f.g']);
  a.b();
  a.c.d();
  a.e.f.g();
  expect(a.b).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(a.c.d).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(a.e.f.g).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

the use case for this is reducing the typing required to create such nested spies

Answer (score 3):

There is no jasmine api that will create this easily for you. You need to create the spies directly, something like this is the best you can get:

```
const a = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
  b: jasmine.createSpy(),
  c: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
    d: jasmine.createSpy()
  }),
  e: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
    d: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({
      f: jasmine.createSpy()
    })
  })
});
```

If you need to do this often, then I'd recommend that you create some sort of function that can recursively extract a spy description and generate a nested spy object from it. But, there is nothing native in Jasmine that does this for you.